# Python - execute mysql string

Tags: python, mysql

I am working on creating tables and loading them with python in vs code. I get the following error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(INTO TABLE `coffee_meta_stackexchange_com`.posts
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  ESCAPED BY '"'
> LINES TERMINATED BY '
> IGNORE 1 LINES;), it must be of type list, tuple or dict

Here's the code:

```
            cursor1.execute("""LOAD DATA INFILE""" + os.path.join(path, i, file),
                            """INTO TABLE `""" + re.sub('[.-]','_', i) + """`.posts
                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  ESCAPED BY '"'
                            LINES TERMINATED BY '""" + "\r\n" +"""' IGNORE 1 LINES;""")
```

I'm not sure why there is an issue. I was able to run the mysql query within MySQL. Alternatively I would like to run some python scripts initially and this is one of them.

I wanted this Python code/query to load a file on a table from a *.csv file that was transformed from an xml off this website's data dump. Appreciate your time, thank you.

Comment: At the end of first line there is a comma which better should be a plus sign.

Comment: This worked. However I got a new error still within the same parameters of this question. ERROR:  SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INFILED:\StackExchange\stackexchangeparser\Output\coffee.meta.stackexchange.com\' at line 1   , Note: I recently reinstalled MySQL again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally get a file to load via mysql connector in python. The issues were the direction of the / or the \ (I haven't tried os.path.basename() yet, but I wanted to return a working path without stating it so this option my work as well. Next issue, the query will return values that = '' when the file attempts to load. So I used SET CASE statement to finally load the csv file. The result are messy but it works. I am still rewriting the query to clean up the values dynamically, and I will post it later.

```
                fixpath = "'" + path + os.path.join(os.path.sep, i, file) + "'"
                fixpath = fixpath.replace('\\', '/')
                
                cursor1.execute("""LOAD DATA INFILE """ + fixpath + 
                        """ INTO TABLE `""" + re.sub('[.-]','_', i) + """`.posts CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  ESCAPED BY '"'
                        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS""" + 
                        """ (Id, PostTypeId, @parentid, @acceptedanswerid, CreationDate, Score, @viewcount, Body, @owneruserid, LastActivityDate, Title, Tags, @answercount, CommentCount, @favoritecount, ContentLicense)""" +
                        """SET ParentId = CASE WHEN @parentid = '' THEN 0 ELSE @parentid END""" +
                        """,AcceptedAnswerId = CASE WHEN @acceptedanswerid = '' THEN 0 ELSE @acceptedanswerid END
                        ,FavoriteCount = CASE WHEN @favoritecount = '' THEN 0 ELSE @favoritecount END
                        ,ViewCount = CASE WHEN @viewcount = '' THEN 0 ELSE @viewcount END
                        ,AnswerCount = CASE WHEN @answercount = '' THEN 0 ELSE @answercount END
                        ,OwnerUserId = CASE WHEN @owneruserid = '' THEN 0 ELSE @owneruserid END;""")
```